# ios - SWRevealViewController segue to last view in navigation controller when receive push notification

Tags: push-notification, segue, appdelegate, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm using SWRevealViewController 2.3.0 in my project. My storyboard is designed as below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/txv0G.png

When the app is not running (completely terminated) and a push notification comes, how to get the **Detail view controller** showed up with a **Back** button to go back **Main view controller**? Some notification values should have passed to the Detail view.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i am doing in this type of case is

you can check if `launchOptions` is not nil `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` as

```
if (launchOptions)
{
    NSDictionary *dic = [launchOptions objectForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[dic objectForKey:@"aps"] forKey:@"PushNotification"];
}
else
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:nil forKey:@"PushNotification"];
}
```

and save in user Defaults as i did.

Now simply When you are in `mainViewController` you can check it as

```
NSDictionary *notification = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"PushNotification"];

if (notification)
{
    // check the dictionary "Push Notification" Key Values that you are receiving to go in `DetailViewController` 
    // Now go to `DetailViewContoller` having your details from `PushNotification`by `performSegueWithIdentifier`

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController" sender:self];

    // make this value nil for normal use 
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:nil forKey:@"PushNotification"];
}
```

if you don't make this userDefaults value nil here, you can use it in DetailViewController too, but don't forget to make nil after use.

Using this way your **BACK** button should show in DetailViewController